# Laravel 4: mcrypt and autoconf not linked

Tags: laravel-4, autoconf, mcrypt

I'm having big problems with mcrypt installation. I followed many tutorials, but it's hopeless.

After installing mcrypt, I got the "Mcrypt extension required" error. 
So I tried to reinstall it using the following command

```
brew install autoconf mcrypt
```

which ended in

```
Warning: autoconf-2.69 already installed, it's just not linked
Warning: mcrypt-2.6.8 already installed, it's just not linked
```

Any ideas how I can link them to my larval project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just want to mention that I'm working on mac OS X Yosemite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need the plain `mcrypt` package, you need the PHP extension.

Depending on your PHP version, you need one of `php53-mcrypt`, `php54-mcrypt`, `php55-mcrypt`, or `php56-mcrypt`.

Don't forget to restart your webserver after installation.

Comment: Thank you. It worked after I used brew link for autoconf freetype libtool mcrypt, then with brew install php56-mcrypt, it's all working now :)

Comment: when I run brew `php55-mrypt` i got another error as `No available formula for php55-mcrypt ` any ideas how to resolve this.